# Populating select with list of objects' unique attribute values?

Tags: angularjs

I'm creating a select dropdown that is going to populate off existing attribute values(unique) of a list of objects.  This is going to be used as a filter.

For example, say I have a list that looks something like this:

```
[
   {
      category: "A"
   },
   {
      category: "B"
   },
   {
      category: "C"
   },
   {
      category: "A"
   }
]
```

I want my dropdown to have the values of A, B, and C.  I could loop through the list and the category attribute and make a unique list, but that seems messy.  Is there anything in Angular that will do this?

Comment: The unique filter in ui.utils package is what you want: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/#/unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for:

[Making a select list in AngularJS](http://plnkr.co/edit/FG0mlhIqNSGpGLyvVJeC?p=preview)

> app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.utils']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.vals = [
   {
      category: "A"
   },
   {
      category: "B"
   },
   {
      category: "C"
   },
   {
      category: "A"
   }
]
});
```

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.2.19"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-utils/0.1.1/angular-ui-utils.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <select ng-model='selvalue' ng-options='val.category for val in vals | unique:category'></select>
    Selected:{{selvalue.category}}
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: OP want a uniqe category list. This code still produce duplicate `A` options.

Comment: This worked perfectly with the unique filter.  Thanks!